# I'm trying to avoid or at least organize better expressions inside if statement in my code

Tags: apex, conditional, expressions

Need help, my code has a lot of expressions in if statement and I'm trying to get rid of it or organize it in a better way.

for example like this:

```
if (fieldNumber==1 && (language=='en' || language=='fr' || language == 'de')){
    code
}

if (fieldNumber==1 && ((language == secondLanguage && language == 'en')|| country == 'PO'){
    code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Implying that your functionality will be expanded I would propose something like that:

```
List<String> languages = new List<String>{'en', 'fr', 'de'};
String eng = languages[0];

if(fieldNumber == 1){

    if(languages.contains(language)){
       //code
     }

    if((language == eng && secondLanguage == eng) || country == 'PO'){
       //code
     }
}
```